# Capture iPhone console logs via command line

Tags: xcode

From terminal is there a way to access a physical iOS device's console log and crash log?

I know there's a way to do it through Xcode but what I'm interested in is doing so via terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Install http://www.libimobiledevice.org

If you have homebrew just run:

```
brew install libimobiledevice
```

Then you view the console log in realtime with:

```
idevicesyslog
```

or view crash reports with:

```
idevicecrashreport
```